# ElasticSearch : field not returned

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to ElasticSearch, please forgive my stupidity.

I cant seem to get the keepalive field out of ES.

```
{
      "_index" : "2013122320",
      "_type" : "log",
      "_id" : "Y1M18ZItTDaap_rOAS5YOA",
      "_score" : 1.0
    }
```

I can get other field out of it cdn:

```
{
      "_index" : "2013122320",
      "_type" : "log",
      "_id" : "2neLlVNKQCmXq6etTE6Kcw",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "fields" : {
        "cdn" : "-"
      }
}
```

The mapping is there:

```
{
  "log": {
    "_timestamp": {
      "enabled": true,
      "store": true
    },
    "properties": {
      "keepalive": {
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

We create a new index every hour using the following perl code

```
create_index(
 index   => $index,
 settings => {
  _timestamp => { enabled => 1, store => 1 },
  number_of_shards      => 3,
  number_of_replicas    => 1,
 },
 mappings => {
  varnish => {
   _timestamp => { enabled => 1, store => 1 },
   properties  => {
    content_length => { type => 'integer' },
    age => { type => 'integer' },
    keepalive => { type => 'integer' },
    host        => { type => 'string', index => 'not_analyzed' },
    time        => { type => 'string', store => 'yes' },
<SNIPPED>
    location    => { type => 'string', index => 'not_analyzed' },

   }
  }
 }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

With so little informations, I can only guess : 
In the mapping you gave, keepalive is not explicitely stored and alasticsearch defaults to no. If you do not store a field, you can only get it via the complete source, wich is stored by default. Or you change, the mapping, adding ("store" : "yes") to your field and reindex.

Good luck with ES, It is well worth a few days of learning.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, DeH. What more information do you need and I will try an gather it. We have a perl script that create new indexes every hour.  
I guess I should add store => 'yes' to my keepalive field like the time field?  

Code is above in my original post.  
Thanks again